# Android and iOS - 2D Game Programming

Tags: android, ios, 2d

Please explain like I'm 5 years old because I don't know about coding.

I want to make 2D games for Android and iOS but I don't know where to start.

Which language is best for making 2D games?

I want to make arcade games like Flappy Bird and want to know best language for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS, natively (meaning you do things with Apple's frameworks/libraries), you have frameworks like [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/), [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/scenekit/), (newly added) [GameplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172) and ReplayKit, etc. SpriteKit is especially focused on 2D. And if you want to develop games this way, Objective C / Swift will be the developing language. I'm not too sure about native Android approach.

That said, if you want to make 2D games and have them available both on iOS and Android, or even on other platforms (web, console etc) as well, why not try a game engine. Something like [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) would be a good idea to start with as it's free if you just want to play with game development. Unity supports C# and JavaScript as the developing language, but other game engines may use different programming languages, and there are many different engines out there.

Comment: Thanks. I will use Unity 2D.

Answer (score 0):

For something cross-platform check out Unity 2D. However please refrain from questions that ask opinion in the future. Stack overflow is for questions that can be answered, not those asking opinions. That's why you got the down votes.